# Cant connect to survey monkey API

Tags: surveymonkey

I am trying to connect to the survey monekey API with this code, which is not working. It says "Invalid API key" even though I got the API from the API console.

```
 public void fetch() {
        String url = "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key=" + apiKey;
        System.out.println("request being sent");
        System.out.println(url);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // byte[] postDataBytes = obj.toJSONString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            URL ourl = new URL(url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ourl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer " + accessToken);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            conn.getRequestProperty(obj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").toString());

            int k = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("The response code received is " + k);
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

            output = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(output);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here's the error:

```
request being sent
https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key=---API-KEY----
The response code received is 200
Output from Server .... 
{"status":3,"errmsg":"Expected object or value"}
```

I just got this url from the API console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular error is generated when an empty string is sent for the POST data.  The API expects an empty object at minimum ("{}").  If the issue pointed out by Miles above was just a typo (using 'getRequestProperty' instead of 'setRequestProperty',) check if toString on an empty JSONObject is returning "" or "{}".

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are using the API key associated with your developer account registered at http://developer.surveymonkey.com, *not* the sample API key the console uses to let you try requests.  The sample api key is not meant to be used with apps, only on the API console.

Comment: Thanks for that! But I'm still getting an error. Question updated above.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're sending a JSON object as a string.

Comment: I think I am sending an object as a string in this part: conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer " + accessToken);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            conn.getRequestProperty(obj.toString().getBytes("UTF-8").toString()); What else do you expect? Can you please answer specifically?

Comment: doesn't "getRequestProperty" get rather than set?